# Which is the best 3D printer to print bodies scanned?

Tags: 3d-models, print-quality

I want to print people's bodies scanned (or get 'minimes', see the [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTgbX.jpg)). And I watched that the printer 'project 660' is [very good to do this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1MTOgCXJegw) ([Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTgbX.jpg)). But, the price of that printer is really expensive, [roughly $60'000](http://www.3dhubs.com/3d-printers/projet-660). And If you want to get a 'minime' printed by that printer, the cost is $230 for a model of 10cm. For me that price is expensive too.

Does anyone know what printer I could use in order to print 'minimes' with:

- Good resolution, or details of the person's face (for a model of 10cm) and a good smooth surface of the model printed ([Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTgbX.jpg)).
- Ability to print complex models such as bodies ([Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTgbX.jpg)) without problem.
- Inexpensive: less than $150 per 'minime'.
- An option to print in color.

Thanks.

*Figure 1: Models printed*

[image: Mimes printed:]

Comment: Hi! This question is very broad, as it has many possible answers. Almost any printer could be an answer, as you haven't included many criteria on what kind of printer you need. Questions that ask for "the best" X are not very suitable for stack exchange, because what is "the best" is very subjective. Could you maybe add some more information based on which the potential answers to this question could be narrowed down?

Comment: Hi, Francis. For the reasons pointed out by Tom, I have to put it *on hold* for now. You may vote for your question to be opened after eventual edits.

Comment: I edited the post, please let me know any problem.

Comment: What does "no expensive" mean? Under $100? Under $500? Under $1000?

Comment: Less than $150. I've just changed it

Comment: What I need to do to skip from the hold?

Comment: Hi, Kuroro! While recommendation questions generally are discouraged here on 3D Printer SE, I am willing to open your question due to your particular requirement of *"a cheap printer that can print in full color"*. In my opinion, this requirement is specific enough to eliminate most common 3D printer alternatives. Good luck! :-)

Comment: where did you get the idea that printing a 10cm "mini-me" costs 230$ ?

Comment: In this video, I saw a copy of a hand if someone knew what it was https://youtu.be/cEJHXDsYeww

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think there exists a printer that meets your requirements. "Cheap"/hobbyist printers roughly fall into two categories:

- FDM: does not meet your requirement for sufficient detail and smooth surfaces in the face (and can not print in color).
- SLA: meets your requirement for detail in the face but can not print in color. If you are willing to drop the color requirement, this would be a good choice.

There are some hobbyist projects to do full color printing, but they are in a rather early stage. One option is [colorpod](http://www.spitstec.nl/) that can be used to convert an FDM printer (such as the Ultimaker, but the principle works with any printer) however it is in a rather early stage of development and not very reliable yet. Another option is [Plan B](http://ytec3d.com/plan-b/) but that is a DIY project and not available for purchase (and is not very mature either).

That leaves you with the commercial color options. You've already ruled out the 3D systems/projet machines. Another (slightly cheaper) commercial option is [MCOR IRIS](http://mcortechnologies.com/3d-printers/iris/) but it also runs in the tens of thousands. While researching this question I stumbled upon [3D Pandoras](http://3dpandoras.com/) but it seems a relatively new company so it may turn out to be a literal Pandora's box (they mention "most affordable filaments" as one of the advantages of their printer even though it doesn't use filament at all) - and prices are not listed on their website.

Comment: Good FDM gives better result than bad SLA and still costs 10 times less.

Comment: Anyone Knows -Mcor ARKe?. It uses paper ... but, is the quality really good for 'minimes'?

Comment: @Kuroro You can see some sample pictures on the [product page](http://mcortechnologies.com/3d-printers/arke-3d-photorealistic-colour-printer/). They don't look bad, but the 3D systems/project/ZCorp machines do a better job.

Comment: Hi Tom van der Zanden.
Is MCOR really bad?, because you wrote: "runs in the tens of thousands". Could you explain me a little more?.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options for printers that can produce high-quality 'minimes' at a lower cost. One option is the Formlabs Form 3, which has a maximum build volume of 14.5 x 14.5 x 18.5 cm and can print in color. Another option is the Prusa i3 MK3S, which has a build volume of 25 x 21 x 20 cm and can also print in color. Both of these printers have good resolution and can handle complex models. Another option is the Creality CR-10, which has a larger build volume of 30 x 30 x 40 cm and can print in color. However, it may have a slightly lower resolution compared to the other two options. These printers range in price from \$500 to \$1000, making them more affordable than the 'project 660'.